# Have to find LastRow VBA solution to be able to enter data using 1 userform for 3 worksheets which can have blank cells in previous rows

Tags: excel, userform

Have searched for an answer, but to no avail. I am a newbie BTW
Thought I found an answer, but after testing it didn't work as I hoped for.
I have made a userform for data entry in 3 different worksheets using the cmdbtn.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Declare variables
Dim wsGuests As Worksheet
Dim wsDiverdetails As Worksheet
Dim wsBookTravel As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

'Set worksheets
Set wsGuests = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Guests")
Set wsDiverdetails = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Diver details")
Set wsBookTravel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Book and Travel")
For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    'Check if the row is completely blank
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        'If the row is completely blank, set LastRow to the current row
        LastRow = i
        'Exit the loop
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
LastRow = Guests.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
wsGuests.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = Me.tbFirst_name.Value
wsGuests.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Me.tbLast_name.Value
etc.
LastRow = wsDiverdetails.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
wsDiverdetails.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = Me.tbCert_level.Value
wsDiverdetails.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Me.tbNod.Value
etc.
LastRow = wsBookTravel.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
wsBookTravel.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Value = Me.tbDep_date.Value
wsBookTravel.Cells(LastRow + 1, 2).Value = Me.tbLeave_date.Value
etc.
End Sub
```

With this:
If all data from userform get filled out then no problem, but when not all entries are filled out then cells in the rows get replaced or empty cells get filled out.

So this is the code I thought would work,which works fine for the first worksheet, but not for the two other sheets.
I have been tinkering with the i, but nothing came out of it.
How can it be solved?
There is another thing I would like to do and that is to give the LastRow automatically an ID number when data gets inserted in the worksheet.
I did try this answer too, but got compile error and duplicate error on Dim LastRow As Long.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim LastRow3 As Long

'Find the last row of data in Sheet1
LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last row of data in Sheet2
LastRow2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last row of data in Sheet3
LastRow3 = ws3.Cells(ws3.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last row of data in all 3 sheets
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Application.Max(LastRow1, LastRow2, LastRow3)

'Go to the last row of data in all 3 sheets
ws1.Range("A" & LastRow).Select

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help that will get this working properly. Thanks in advance